# What does for the summer mean?

Tags: phrases

I'm wondering whether "for the summer" means "for this summer" or "for every summer"?

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Please add an example sentence to your question - it's impossible to answer this without context.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Actually, I'm doing an exercise. And the full question is "I work/am working at the local library for the summer"

Comment: Colloquially it means 'for this summer'. Otherwise one would say something like 'I work on farms during the summertime'.

Comment: It is defined only by context. 'Next year, we're going to Skegness for the summer.' // 'In the 90s, we always used to go to Cleethorpes for the summer.'